# How to stop parameters from changing after painting on an image?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

The program that I’m trying to write gets some input and has to insert images into cells according to the input(which are parameters for a square). It has an add button which, after you change the parameters, inserts another row with the information + image.

I have a QPainter which paints the parameters next to the square/image everytime someone changes them.

The problem is that when the parameters are changed, all the images are changed and I want only the last one to be.

This is a part of my code:

```
from RD2 import Ui_RD
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QImage, QPen, QColor, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrintDialog, QPrinter

imagePath1 = "/Users/calinap/Desktop/PyQt5/NewRD/Pics/1.png"
class ImgWidget1(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parent,*args, **kwargs):
        super(ImgWidget1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        #print(self.parent.a.text())
        self.pic = QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath1)
        self.setPixmap(self.pic)

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QColor('red'))
        #painter.begin(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.pic)
        painter.drawText(75,15, str(self.parent.A))
        painter.drawText(5,20, str(self.parent.B))
        painter.drawText(75,30, str(self.parent.C))
        painter.drawText(135,20, str(self.parent.D))
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.ui = Ui_RD()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.printButton.clicked.connect(self.handlePrint)
        self.ui.addButton.clicked.connect(self.adauga)

        self.nr_row = 0


    def adauga(self):
        self.A = self.ui.a.text()
        self.B = self.ui.b.text()
        self.C = self.ui.c.text()
        self.D = self.ui.d.text()

        self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow(self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount())

        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(self.nr_row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(self.diam))
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(self.nr_row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(self.lungimetot))

        if int(self.A) != 0 and int(self.B) != 0 and int(self.C) != 0 and int(self.D) != 0:
        self.img1 = ImgWidget1(self.ui)
        self.ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(self.nr_row, 3, ImgWidget1(self))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the arguments as parameters instead of an object so that the information of the other widgets will no longer be modified

```
class ImgWidget1(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def __init__(self, parameters parent=None):
        super(ImgWidget1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pic = QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath1)
        self.setPixmap(self.pic)
        self.parameters = parameters

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QColor('red'))
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.pic)
        A, B, C, D = self.parameters
        painter.drawText(75,15, str(A))
        painter.drawText(5,20, str(B))
        painter.drawText(75,30, str(C))
        painter.drawText(135,20, str(D))

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def adauga(self):
        A = self.ui.a.text()
        B = self.ui.b.text()
        C = self.ui.c.text()
        D = self.ui.d.text()

        self.ui.tableWidget.insertRow(self.ui.tableWidget.rowCount())

        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(self.nr_row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(self.diam))
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(self.nr_row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(self.lungimetot))

        if int(A) != 0 and int(B) != 0 and int(C) != 0 and int(D) != 0:
            widget = ImgWidget1((A, B, C, D))
            self.ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(self.nr_row, 3, widget)
```